# I need help in solving Prime from the CS50 course

Tags: cs50

I am new to coding and I am having a stressful time to solve Prime in CS50. Anyone can help me and explain what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool prime(int number);

int main(void)
{
    int min;
    do
    {
        min = get_int("Minimum: ");
    }
    while (min < 1);

    int max;
    do
    {
        max = get_int("Maximum: ");
    }
    while (min >= max);

    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (prime(i))
        {
            printf("%i\n", i);
        }
    }
}

bool prime(int number)
{
    if(number <2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (number <= 3 )
    {
        return true;
        {
            if(number % 2 ==0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            int limit = number /2;
            for(int i = 3; i <= limit; i +=2)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
}
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried to print prime numbers from 1 to 50. Instead it prints all numbers starting from 2 until 50

Comment: When `i` is 1, `prime` returns `false`.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I was able to fix it and indeed there where a couple off mistakes here and there.